# Service not working when upgrading Angular 4 to 7

Tags: angular, typescript, http, service, angular-http-interceptors

I have upgraded my angular app from 4 to latest version 7. After so many errors I finally got it to work but now there is one problem: services are not working, like it is not giving any error in the console but not working as well.

I think the problem is with my Http interceptor and the factory in which I am missing something.

Can someone tell me what the issue is, exactly?

**Http interceptor**

```js
  constructor(
    backend: HttpBackend,
    private store: Store<any>,
    private spinnerService: SpinnerService
  ) {
    super(backend);
  }

  request( url: string | HttpRequest<any>, options?: any): Observable<any> {
    this.showLoader();
    return this.tryCatch(super.request(this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)))
  }

  get(url: string, options?: any): Observable<any> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.tryCatch(super.get(url));
  }

  post(url: string, body: string, options?: any): Observable<any> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.tryCatch(
      super.post(url, body)
    );
  }

  put(url: string, body: string, options?: any): Observable<any> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.tryCatch(
      super.put(url, body)
    );
  }

  delete(url: string, options?: any): Observable<any> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.tryCatch(super.delete(url));
  }

  patch(url: string, body: any, options?: any): Observable<any> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return this.tryCatch(
      super.patch(url, body)
    );
  }

  private updateUrl(req: string) {
    return environment.origin + req;
  }

  private getRequestOptionArgs(options?: any): any {
    if (options.headers == null) {
      options.headers = new HttpHeaders();
    }
    options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    options.headers.append(
      'Authorization',
      ` Bearer ${sessionStorage.AccessToken}`
    );

    return options;
  }

  private tryCatch(obs: Observable<any>) {
    return obs.pipe(catchError((error: HttpResponse<any>, caught) => {
      if (error.status === 401 && sessionStorage.AccessToken) {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        this.store.dispatch({type: 'LOGOUT'});
      }
      this.hideLoader();
      return observableThrowError(error);
    }));
  }
```

**Http factory**

```
export function httpFactory(xhrBackend: HttpXhrBackend, store: Store<any>, spinnerService: SpinnerService): HttpClient {
  return new InterceptedHttp(xhrBackend, store, spinnerService);
}
```

**provider in app module**

```
 {
   provide: HttpClient,
   useFactory: httpFactory,
   deps: [HttpXhrBackend, Store, SpinnerService]
 },
```

Whenever I login it just starts loading, nothing else, no error or anything and when I comment out the provider in the app module it says "404 not found error".

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Several changes happened between those versions, won't require much work, I've been there too.

Here is a helper, select origin version and destination, you will get a step by step guide of required changes.

[update.angular.io](https://update.angular.io/)

Comment: @usmansaleem You can try to recreate the interceptor in the new version, had exactly the same issue, in my case rxjs imports were the problem.

Comment: like how? there is not imports in my http interceptor from rxjs except throwError and catchError and it was working fine in angular 4

Comment: @usmansaleem I used [this guide](https://scotch.io/@vigneshsithirai/angular-6-7-http-client-interceptor-with-error-handling) and remade the whole thing pretty quick.